# sh.exe": node: command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-7

I'm trying to run a javascript file in Gitbash but getting this error.

```
$ node chrome-devtools-autosave-server/index.js
sh.exe": node: command not found
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

How to solve this?

**My OS is Windows 7 (64 Bit)**

Comment: perhaps index.js contains something tring to use "sh.exe" - can you post the relevant part of that code ?

Comment: What happens if you run a command that's certainly not there? Same error message, or another?

Comment: @Yahia - I'm trying to use this plugin https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave/blob/master/README.mdown

Comment: Nothing to do with git. Removed tag.

Comment: @JitendraVyas I don't think that this is meant to be used with Windows... you wil have to setup some unix-like environment (mingw / cygwin / whatever...) and then try it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Node is not 'visible' in MINGW32 by default, only in the Windows Command Terminal. Same goes for npm.

How to add it (if you have Node installed), [from the official MINGW FAQ](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/help/cpp_mingw-faq.php):

> MSYS uses a Bourne-like shell, hence 
>       you can change the PATH using the export command.
>       The easiest way to add 
>       something to the end of the PATH is with the command:
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:directory-to-add
> ```

So you have to add the directory where Node is installed (probably something like C:\Program Files\nodejs).

Comment: OK SO i need to install http://nodejs.org/#download in my Windows PC. I'm downloading and installing this http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.6/node-v0.6.6.msi

Comment: I've installed Node.js on my system and path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`

Comment: I tried to run `export PATH=$PATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` but it's giving error

Comment: Ah if you already have installed Node and you're in the Windows Command Terminal, you can use it now. `node -v` to test

Comment: Then everything is ok, Node has installed correctly. Look here for tutorials and more info on node: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info Also, consider accepting/voting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: +1 for the helpful advice! After successfully installing prerequisite packages for Cygwin, cloned nodejs, and built it, I got the error message "-bash: node: command not found" when trying to test my nodejs installation. However I did like you said and added the following path and it worked! (export PATH=$PATH:~/github/nodejs)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing double quotes for path varible

export PATH=$PATH:"C:\Program Files\nodejs"

Answer (score 1):

For me, I am using the Git Bash Shell, and what I had to do to add the bin file to my PATH variable is use this syntax:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:"c/bin/node"
```

You would think that it would be

```
 export PATH=$PATH:"C:\bin\node"
```

but that wasn't working for me. Hope this helps others that are running into the same issue.